# Add Developers in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, beta-testing

Assume I have an Xcode project running on Github and multiple developers. I have a new developer who will clone the git repository and start working on the app. I want to add his iOS devices as devices that can run the builds without having to reissue certificates and do all that long process on the iOS Dev Center. How can I do that? I want him to clone the repo, connect his device to Xcode and be able to run the app on his device.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If he is a paid iOS developer and there is no reason to use a specific provisioning profile you won't need to do anything. Xcode can automatically provision his device when he compiles it. Just use the automatic profile selection for your development builds in the build settings.

If it is important that you both use the correct provisioning profile (for example to test push notifications) there is no way around adding his device to the profile on the developer portal. Plus you will need to let him sign the binary as you, using your developer certificate and private key (which you will have to export from Keychain on your development machine).

Comment: So do I just add his device in iOS Dev Center? I've seen projects that literally just ask for a developer's UDID and it works. Without having to export their certificate and send it to the developer for him to open it with Keychain etc... How is that done?

Comment: That is the case when you just want the other person to be able to run a build that you have compiled yourself. For example if he is a tester. In this case you want the other person to also be able to compile the app. The app is code-signed when it is compiled. The person doing the compilation must have access to a valid key-pair for this purpose.

Comment: But again: If you are not using push notifications, in-app purchases or similar features there is no reason that the other developer has to use the same keys and provisioning profile just for development. He can just sign it with his own keys. You probably don't want to give your developer keys away for this purpose. It might even be in violation of your developer agreement with Apple if that person is not a registered developer. The official way to do this is to create a company account and set the other developer's account up as a team agent. More about team roles here: http://bit.ly/NeXbq3

Comment: Thanks for the link! Makes sense now. I have an Individual license and not an Enterprise one so unfortunately, I can't do what I was aiming to do. Thanks anyway - this will help me when if I ever upgrade.

Comment: Yes. But you can probably find a way to collaborate where he signs his own builds and you sign the "official" test builds and the App Store build with your keys.